# How do I deploy to a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-7, xna, device

I've been coding something in XNA 4.0 and running things through an emulator. I tried deploying to an actual Windows Phone 7 device but the compiler said there were deployment errors. It says htis exactly: 'There were deployment errors. Continue?' and if I hit 'yes' I get another messagebox which says 'unable to start debugging'.

I've looked online and can't find any resources on this weird problem I'm having. I've plugged in the phone via USB but that's all I can think of doing, am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to deploy to a device: either through Visual Studio or running a series of commands from the CLI (useful when delivering builds to clients).

In your case, you are trying from Visual Studio. The message/s you receive basically means that it cannot find a device to deploy to because either it is **not connected** or the Zune software is not installed and/or running.

**Steps to try:**
1. Check your USB connections.
2. Ensure that [Zune software](http://www.zune.net/en-US/products/software/download/default.htm) is installed and running.

You also need to unlock the device with your marketplace credentials before trying to deploy to the phone. You will need to register for an **AppHub** account on MSDN by visiting https://users.create.msdn.com/. You unlock the device in the Zune software.

It is free for Students through the [Microsoft Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) initiative and $99 USD annual subscription for commercial or individual developers. For more information about AppHub read this [article](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/10/11/introducing-app-hub-for-windows-phone-7-amp-indie-game-developers.aspx).

Comment: Where do I get credentials to unlock it?

Comment: @Meds: Updated my answer. Unless you need to use features on the device (e.g. Camera or GPS) you can hold off registering for the AppHub for awhile and develop using the emulator.

Comment: Another important part if you do this from VS: make sure that at the time of running the app from VS using F5, the phone is not in the lock screen.

Answer (score 2):

Check the drivers installed when you plugged it in via USB. You'll see the device in device manager when installed and connected.

If they didn't, you may need to get a replacement USB to USB Micro B cable, or check you're using the original cable supplied with the device.

If the driver's are installed, Zune should load whenever you plug it in.

Also you can check booting your PC and device (pull battery) clean... and whilst not plugged in until all fully booted.